# Retrieve a Regex Pattern from a MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, regex, jdbc

I have a table in MySQL containing regex pattern such as : `FILE\\\\d{1,4}`.
But while trying to retrieve the pattern value with a Java code, it seems like the value is not in the good format.
How can I store this value in MySQL, to be able to retrieve the exact value I want in the code : `FILE\\d{1,4}`
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Inside the quotes presumably.

Comment: Please, I don't get you ?

Comment: Ok, wait I'm connecting to the my MySQL server...

Comment: I've retrieved exactly the value you need.

Comment: Hey, did you get what I've said?

Comment: Give me a code sample. I will better understand !

Comment: I am talking about retrieving the sample value with JDBC.

Comment: I'm not using JDBC, however if you search for some of my answers you will find some JDBC code if it's not removed yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK now. For this case, I just have to insert the regex pattern in the table with 4 backslash (\\) and while I retrieve it from the data base within JAVA, I got two backslashs (\). It is due to the escape character that MySQL applied.
Thank you !

Comment: Note: you can Accept your own answer as the correct one if you like.